# Convert HTML Webpage encoded in SHIFT-JIS to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, encoding, shift-jis

I'm viewing some webpages on the waybackmachine and am struggling to read the Japanese because its encoded in SHIFT-JIS. Is there some javascript I can apply to the strings to convert the garbled text to something readable?

Example Text:

```
¦‚±‚Ì¤•iƒWƒƒƒ“ƒ‹‚Ì’†‚©‚çƒL[ƒ[ƒh‚Åiž‚ñ‚ÅŒŸõ‚ª‚Å‚«‚Ü‚·B
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh seems like the simplest way to do this in Safari is just `View > Text Encoding > Japanese (Shift JIS)`